# Как сделать QMessageBox со spinBox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Я попытался сделать в `QtDesigner` шаблон диалогового окна, но возникли проблемы с ссылкой на метод вызывающий данное окно, теперь я хотел бы узнать - можно ли а `QMessageBox` вставить spinBox? Работаю в PyQt5

Comment: Узнать конечно можно, но вам надо показать что у вас есть (минимально-воспроизводимый пример), лучше рассказать, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Хочу сделать диалоговое окно со spinBox, не более

Comment: покажите код, который есть сейчас, тогда глядишь и помогут

Comment: Дело в том, что сейчас никакого кода нет

Comment: Просто нужно считать данные из spinBox

Answer (score 1):

Хотя ваши высказывания противоречивы, с одной стороны вы пишите `попытался сделать в QtDesigner шаблон диалогового окна, но возникли проблемы ...`, с другой стороны - `Дело в том, что сейчас никакого кода нет`. Странно как-то.

Все делается как обычно:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MessageBox(QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.spinbox = QSpinBox(self)
        self.spinbox.setRange(-99, 99)                                                      
        self.spinbox.setSingleStep(1)                                                     
        self.spinbox.setValue(66)                                                           


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        container = QWidget()
        containerLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        container.setLayout(containerLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)

        self.label = QLabel()
        button = QPushButton('Вызвать Диалоговое окно', clicked=self.onClicked)

        containerLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        containerLayout.addWidget(button)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.messageBox = MessageBox()
        msg = self.messageBox.exec_()

        self.label.setText(str(self.messageBox.spinbox.value()))


if __name__=="__main__":        
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]